# nginx - how to redirect depending on a range of IP addresses?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, ipv4

I am trying to make a site only accessible from within the local network and people from the external network will get a static page saying some other message.

This is what I am trying to do but it does not seem to work. Where have I gone wrong?

```
         if ($remote_addr != 192.168.1.0/24) {
                   rewrite ^/* /covid19 last;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$remote_addr` is a single IP address (e.g. `192.168.1.123`) so it will not directly compare with the string `192.168.1.0/24`.

If you are comparing an IP address to a `/24` block, you can use a regular expression that only checks the first three numbers.

For example:

```
if ($remote_addr !~ "^192\.168\.1\.") { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It works and has helped me very much. Thank you again for helping me out when I was stuck. I do appreciate it very much.